# data source for report viewer control in WPF

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, parameters, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I have a ReportViewer control in a WindowsFormsHost tag in my WPF application.  When I use this code:

```
    rptViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ...

    List<ReportParameter> parms = new List<ReportParameter>();
    parms.Add(new ReportParameter("regionID", "01"));
    rptViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);

    rptViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I get an error about a data source instance not being supplied.  I can run the stored procedure manually and then use it to populate a datasource object, like...

```
var dt = DAL.GetData()
var rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
rptViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
```

And this will cause the report to display, but then I am passing in my parameters to the GetData() method rather than to the report; this doesn't seem right.  In my SSRS project, I am using a shared datasource, and it allows me to pass in the parameters on the report front end as I would expect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ProcessingMode = Local, then YOU are responsible for large portions of teh report.  You or your application defined which parameters there are, how data is loaded, & what sub-report or drill through events do.  You must explicitly code these.  If the ProcessingMode = Remote, then all of these elements are handled by the reporting server.  Microsoft doesn't spell this out very clearly in MSDN, but I can see their justification being "if you are going to host the report in your app, then you can be responsible for all the details".